# fadeIn doesn't fire the for the first mouseover

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade

I have a small problem with my JS code in which the fadeIn method doesn't fire the first time it is called, but it works every time afterwards. Here is my code:

```
var count=0;
$( '.DropsLineNotes' ).each(function(){
    count++;

    var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    var hoverText = $(this).find( '.notesText' ).html();
    console.log(hoverText)
    //creating overlay
    $( '<div>' ).attr({
                    'id': 'overlay'+count,
                    'class': 'allOverlays'
                    })
                .css({
                    'z-index':5,
                    'position':'absolute',
                    'background-color':"#FFFFC2",
                    'border-style': 'ridge',
                    'border-width': 'thick',
                    'border-color': '#6699FF',
                    'padding': '10px'
                })
                .appendTo( 'body' )
                .show()
                .html(hoverText);

    console.log("overlay1 = "+$('#overlay1').text())
    console.log("overlay2 = "+$('#overlay2').text())
    console.log("overlay3 = "+$('#overlay3').text())

    var $image = $( '<img>' ).attr({
        src: 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/runescapefanfiction/images/d/d5/DropsLine_info.png/revision/latest?cb=20150822080442',
        alt: 'Info'
    }),
        $link = $( '<span>' ).attr('id','overlayLink'+count)
        .append( $image )
        .on("mouseenter", function(){
            //get mouse co-ords
            $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
                currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
                currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
            });

            //find which overlay is linked to this link
            var overlayNumber = $(this).attr('id').split('k')[1]
            $('#overlay'+overlayNumber).css({
                'left': currentMousePos.x,
                'top': currentMousePos.y
            }).fadeIn(200);
            console.log("overlay has appeared")
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function() {
            var overlayNumber = $(this).attr('id').split('k')[1]
            //if not hovering on overlay
            if($('#overlay'+overlayNumber+':hover').length == 0)
                $('#overlay'+overlayNumber).fadeOut(100);
        });

        $('.allOverlays').on("mouseleave", function() {
            $('.allOverlays').fadeOut(100);
        });

    $( this ).append( $link );
})
```

In the lines below I reposition the div element overlay and then have it fade in, however the element doesn't fade in the first time I trigger the mouseover event.

```
//find which overlay is linked to this link
var overlayNumber = $(this).attr('id').split('k')[1]
$('#overlay'+overlayNumber).css({
     'left': currentMousePos.x,
      'top': currentMousePos.y
}).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: Are your targeted elements not displayed by default? Otherwise, of course, `fadeIn()` wouldn't have any effect on the first time you hovered it, it is already shown  EDIT: just checking your code, it appears you already show elements, so...

Comment: The elements aren't visible at first, after hovering over then the first time, the elements still aren't visible, but every time after that the fadein() takes effect

Comment: Can you provide a working example?